# Ошибка file_get_contents

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток.
Пытаюсь получить страны через вк АПИ.

```
$params = http_build_query($options);
$url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/'.$method.'?'.$params.'&access_token='.$token;
$response = file_get_contents($url);
return $response;
```

Но,выдает ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Гугл выдал,что надо в php.ini раскомментировать строку "extension=php_openssl.dll"
Но,она и так у меня там открыта.
В чем может быть еще проблема?
Ранее скрипт работал,просто перезапустил XAMPP.
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: может просто слишком много сделали запросов и Вас немножко "прибанили"? подождите часок-другой и попробуйте снова

Comment: та в том то и дело,только сейчас включил и сел за работу,а тут такая херня :С
Ну ладно,благодарю за ответ,может и в этом проблема :С

Comment: @tweeker А догадаться воспользоваться хостингом, VPS - у вас ума не хватило? Так и гипотетическая проблема с баном решится, и настраивать, возможно, ничего не придется - на хостинге уже настроено.

Comment: в любом случае, самое правильное в этом случае - это запустить wireshark (или tcpdump, если это сервер) и потом смотреть. Там будет понятнее. Сервер может явно сообщить о превышенных лимитах или незаполненном параметре. а file_get_contents о многом интересном просто умолчит.

Comment: @KoVadim С Wireshark даже специалисту работать сложно, особенно при SSL, а тут новичку который никогда не видел нормальных запросов там и не с чем сравнить, да и что там понимать? Я думаю, что в этом случае по сети ничего не будет отправлено, так как запрос вообще не отправляется дальше PHP по вышеуказанной причине.

Comment: *С Wireshark даже специалисту работать сложно* - круто, я тогда получается круче специалиста:) (и это логично, потому что я закончил магистратуру:)))))) )

Comment: @KoVadim прогуглил Wireshark ,слишком сложно для меня пока что :С
Так все по идеи отправляется,в phpStorm через консоль,все возвращается,а сервер что-то тупит :С

Comment: @Rou1997 запрос отправляется,даже возвращает значение(консоль в phpStorm отрабатывает все) просто что-то сервер тупит :С

Comment: @tweeker И какое же значение он возвращает?

Comment: @KoVadim Да нет, просто вы работаете мало)))))))))))))

Comment: @Rou1997 {"response":[{"cid":19,"title":"Австралия"},{"cid":20,"title":"Австрия"},{"cid":5,"title":"Азербайджан"},Строку со странами

Comment: @tweeker Тогда в чем проблема. Отключите в том скрипте error_reporting и пойдет.